# MySQL implementation of connection pools

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Does MySQL jdbc driver has built in support for database connection pools? (like Oracle has OracleDataSource class)

I did a thorough search but couldn't find any. I know that I can use external libraries such as dbcp or boneCp and also that application servers such as tomcat and jboss supports connection  pools.

But I would be interested to know if MySQL does have it's own implementation of connection pools.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [JDBC specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf) (see in particular page 68) supports connection pooling, so any modern driver has that capability. However, the intention isn't for JDBC drivers to maintain their own connection pools;  so whether you're using [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html) or Oracle driver, you still need the connection pool implementation provided by an application server or a third party library.

Unless of course you want to try [rolling your own](http://www.rndblog.com/how-to-set-up-a-mysql-connection-pool-in-java/). o.O

The relevant JDBC interfaces are [javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html) and [javax.sql.PooledConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/PooledConnection.html).

In the [latest MySql driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), the corresponding implementation classes are `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` and `MysqlPooledConnection` (both in package com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional). You may find [these code examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource) interesting - they're using a class called MiniConnectionPoolManager as the connection pool implementation.

Comment: A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is **not** a connection pool (although some drivers incorrectly implement it as one); it is the datasource to be **used by** a connection pool.

Comment: Thank you @gknicker. But I'm confused... can you clarify what you meant by the last paragraph please

Comment: @Sachini I was trying to incorporate the warning comment from Mark Rotteveel. I've clarified it now.

Comment: @gknicker `MiniConnectionPoolManager` again is not in the JDBC driver right? (I found it [here](http://www.source-code.biz/miniconnectionpoolmanager/) ) So I'll conclude that MySQL JDBC driver DOES NOT have a built-in Connection Pool implementation like Oracle. Correct me if I'm wrong :) Thanks

Comment: That's correct. Honestly I didn't think OracleDataSource had its own connection pool implementation, but I see now it does.